# Android screen disabeling on activity launch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

there's a small annoying bug that I cant get rid off.
After every activity that I launch in my app, the screen disables itself (goes darker) I have to tap the screen twice and on jellybean I have to press the back button twice to disable screen.

I have used

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

as well as

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

but the problem still presists... I think its really bad ux so need a fix....and go....

Comment: Hoping that this can help. [Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Comment: @AshishJohn  you have not put anything here :)